# Use MyPy with typing.DefaultDict with fixed factory function

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, defaultdict, python-typing

#### I want to do something like this:

```py
from functools import partial
from typing import DefaultDict

def five() -> int:
    return 5  # whatever.

MyDefaultDict = partial(DefaultDict[str, int], five)

my_mapping: MyDefaultDict = MyDefaultDict(x=4)

print(my_mapping['x'])
print(my_mapping['y'])
```

- The new type/class thing `MyDefaultDict` is declared once and has a single name.
- `MyDefaultDict` can be used like a class constructor, and its signature is the same as `dict`'s, the only difference being that what you get is a `defaultdict` with `five` as its factory.
- **MyPy should understand** `MyDefaultDict` **to be the same as (or, preferably, a sub-class of)** `DefaultDict[str, int]`**. This is the part that doesn't work in the above code.**
- Unnecessary for my current use, but a nice-to-have in the general case: `MyDefaultDict` should actually have class properties (*e.g.* static methods) inherited from `defaultdict`.

It's not surprising that `partial` isn't suitable.
`partial` plays poorly with MyPy in general, and *at best* it would be understood as returning some kind of `Callable`, which wouldn't be a sensible type for `my_mapping`. (The actual failure reported is "`scratch.py:9: error: Variable "scratch.MyDefaultDict" is not valid as a type`".)

A variety of other things seem like they *could* work, but I haven't been able to get them to:

#### Subclass and override `__init__`

```py
class MyDefaultDict(DefaultDict[str, int]):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        DefaultDict[str, int].__init__(self, five, *args, **kwargs)
```

Passes MyPy.

> File "scratch.py", line 9, in `__init__`
> `DefaultDict[str, int].__init__(self, five, *args, **kwargs)`
> TypeError: `__init__()` got an unexpected keyword argument 'x'

#### Subclass and override `__new__`

```py
class MyDefaultDict(DefaultDict[str, int]):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls, five, *args, **kwargs)
```

Passes MyPy.
"`KeyError: 'y'`"; the factory function isn't being used.

#### Wrap `partial` in something to make it look like a type

I tried `type` with three args, `typing.NewType`, and `types.new_class`. As far as I can tell this isn't a problem any of them are intended to solve.

I looked into metaclasses briefly and didn't see how they might help with this problem.

I'm using python 3.8, but answers for other versions might be workable.

#### Does anyone know the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

While writing the above I realized that different ways of overriding `__init__` give different results.

This also doesn't work:

```py
class MyDefaultDict(DefaultDict[str, int]):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, five, *args, **kwargs)
```

> File "scratch.py", line 9, in `__init__`
> `super().__init__(self, five, *args, **kwargs)`
> TypeError: first argument must be callable or None

**This *does* work; it would be nice to understand *why*:**

```py
class MyDefaultDict(DefaultDict[str, int]):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(five, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Is this an answer to the question, or an extension to the question?

Comment: Well as far as I've been able to tell it does accomplish the stuff I was originally trying to do, so I _think_ it's a usable answer. On the other hand I don't understand why the different ways of writing the child-class's `__init__` give such different results. I just found the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) where it's mentioned briefly that the 0-arg form of `super` magically(?) binds to `self`. So maybe the only remaining question is why the first attempt at overriding `__init__` didn't work.

Comment: ``super().__init__(self, ...`` passes ``self`` twice – once as the expected ``self`` and once as the *first argument* default-callable. The ``TypeError: first argument must be callable or None`` effectively says that ``self`` is not callable.